# asp.net core development model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Error.
An error occurred while processing your request.
Development Mode
Swapping to Development environment will display more detailed information about the error that occurred.

Development environment should not be enabled in deployed applications, as it can result in sensitive information from exceptions being displayed to end users. For local debugging, development environment can be enabled by setting the ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT environment variable to Development, and restarting the application.

how do i use the development model after publish iis

Comment: Try setting environment variable inside aspNetCore element in the web.config. Something like `<aspNetCore....>      <environmentVariables>
        <environmentVariable name="ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" value="Development" />
      </environmentVariables></aspNetCore>`. You can set it in your project and publish-iis should preserve this.

Comment: thanks you very much!

Comment: @Pawel This should be added as the answer.

Comment: @OctoCode - Thanks for bringing this to my attention. I was not aware that the comment had that many upvotes - turned it to an answer.

Answer (score 13):

You can try setting the environment variable inside the `aspNetCore` element in the `web.config` like this:

```
<aspNetCore....> 
  <environmentVariables> 
    <environmentVariable name="ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" value="Development" /> 
  </environmentVariables>
</aspNetCore>.
```

Such a change to web.config should be preserved during publish.

Comment: Where should the `web.config` file be located in the project?

Comment: In the application root

Comment: MMM, there is no web.config in new asp.net core projects, instead there are appsettings.json

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/?tabs=aspnetcore2x section "web.config" - web.config is not for the app but for IIS and needed when you use IIS as a reverse proxy for your ASP.NET Core app.