# .netcore 2.1 application deployed to IIS produced an error

Tags: xml, iis, .net-core, iis-10

i created a new ASP.NET Core 2.1 Web Application using the Angular Template.

Ran locally in both Debug and Release mode with success.

Created a publish profile to file system, it published successfully to a local folder.

installed: `.NET Core 2.1 Runtime & Hosting Bundle for Windows`
Then in IIS,

1. Created a new Application pool- that uses `.net CLR` = "No Managed Code"
2. Then under `Default Web Site` > created new application that uses the new application pool that i have created, and point to the file-system, to the published directory that published with the help of VS 2017

when i `Browse` to the appliction, this message appear in the browser
[image]

So in `web.config` file i changed, `environmentVariable` to Development in order to see the error

```
 <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\WebApplication1.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout">
    <environmentVariables>
      <environmentVariable name="ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" value="Development" />
    </environmentVariables>
  </aspNetCore>
```

Then i see the error
[image]

I have no clue on what to do next, i have already tried to search for solutions for that, on Stack-overflow and Google
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39737585/asp-net-core-deployment-to-iis-error-development-environment-should-not-be-enab/39737834), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38020264/asp-net-core-development-model) and a lot more.

when i am setting `stdoutLogEnabled` to `true` in `web.config`, then i see this in the logs of the application

> Hosting environment: Production
>   Content root path: C:\prodSites\beedeal
>   Now listening on: http://127.0.0.1:26261
>   Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
>   warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy.HttpsRedirectionMiddleware[3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39737585/asp-net-core-deployment-to-iis-error-development-environment-should-not-be-enab/39737834)
>         Failed to determine the https port for redirect.
>   fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FTOXw.png)
>         An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
>   System.InvalidOperationException: The SPA default page middleware could not return the default page '/index.html' because it was not found, and no other middleware handled the request.
>   Your application is running in Production mode, so make sure it has been published, or that you have built your SPA manually. Alternatively you may wish to switch to the Development environment.
>
> at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.SpaDefaultPageMiddleware.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.b__1(HttpContext
>   context, Func`1 next)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.UseExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass0_1.b__1(HttpContext
>   context)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
>   context)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
>   httpContext)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
>   context)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
>   context)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
>   context)

but didn't find a solution for that..

Comment: There seems to be something that tries to start the angular development server (package.json > scripts > start should call something like ng start). If so, that's wrong. For production, your angular app muss be build using ng build and that will produce static files to be delivered by IIS.

Comment: Enable developers exception page by default and don't switch environment to dev. See what happens.

Comment: @ChristophLütjen  i used Visual Studio publish process and the out put folder seems to be have static files, created in the process of publish through Visual Studio, so i am not sure what you ask..

Comment: I don't know anything about IIS, I just see in your error message that it seems to try to run ng start. And this is wrong and so that's something you could check why that happens.

Answer (score 0):

followed [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZZfRlBMHds8), i finally successfully deployed the application to IIS,

I think that the problem with my non-working try is that that i placed the new `.net core` site under

`Default Web Site` IIS folder, and for `.net core` application it's not allowed (you can't mix .net core application and .net framework application under the `default web site` folder (that was meant for `.net framework` applications)).
`.net core` app uses different configuration + needs to run with `no managed code` application pool.